# Number examples in a tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I snagged some of this code from MATHETEX on youtube. However, my examples start with 0.1 then 0.2, etc.  How can I make them start with 1, then 2, etc.  From the youtube video, his numbering is correct.

I can't seem to get it right.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[many,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section ]{Ex}{ %PROBLEM IS HERE 
breakable,
enhanced,
height=4cm,
 fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3mm, yshift=-3mm},
boxed title style={colback=cyan!15},
coltitle=red,
colback=white,
title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
}


\begin{document}
            \begin{Ex}  
                If \(y=\left(x^2+1\right)^3\) then \(\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\)
            
            \end{Ex}
            
                \begin{Ex}
                    If \(y=\left(3x-2x^2\right)^3\), then \(\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\)
                \end{Ex}
                
                \begin{Ex}
                    If \(y=\dfrac{-7}{\left(2x-3\right)^2}\), then \(\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\)
                \end{Ex}        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, your counter is called `within section`. But since you didn't called a section in your MWE, the section counter is still 0. Try add a `\section` before your first environment.

Comment: If you just remove `number within=section` you'll have the plain 1,2,3... numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment: If you use the init option `number within=section`, the first digit in your call of `\thetcbcounter` represents the section, since the `tcbcounter` with that option is kind of embedded into the `section` counter.

If you have a section in the document, the `0` changes to the current section number:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[many,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section ]{Ex}{ %PROBLEM IS HERE 
breakable,
enhanced,
height=4cm,
 fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3mm, yshift=-3mm},
boxed title style={colback=cyan!15},
coltitle=red,
colback=white,
boxsep=10pt, % <---! Added only as suggestion
title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
}


\begin{document}

\section{A section}
            \begin{Ex}  
                If \(y=\left(x^2+1\right)^3\) then \(\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\)
            
            \end{Ex}

\section{Another section}           

                \begin{Ex}
                    If \(y=\left(3x-2x^2\right)^3\), then \(\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\)
                \end{Ex}
                
                \begin{Ex}
                    If \(y=\dfrac{-7}{\left(2x-3\right)^2}\), then \(\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\)
                \end{Ex}        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Furthermore, I recommend that you add somethin like `boxsep=10pt` to your tcb-options because with your settings the formulas are very close to the margin. I added that in my code, of course, you can delete this line.

Comment: Thank you! Looks much better